# Baseball Flight Path

Tags: physics

I am trying to come up with an equation that is able to estimate the magnitude of the velocity a ball after it travelled a certain distance in the $x-$direction.

I came across the following site [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Physical_Modeling_in_MATLAB_(Downey)/12%3A_Two_Dimensions/12.04%3A_Drag_Force#:%7E:text=The%20drag%20coefficient%20for%20a,baseball%20is%200.0042%20m2.) and want to incorporate drag into the equation.

In the article, it discusses $\overrightarrow{F_d}=-\frac{1}{2}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} $ which we can divide by $m$ to figure out the acceleration of the drag force $\overrightarrow{a_d}=\frac{\overrightarrow{F_d}}{m}=-\frac{1}{2m}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} $.

Does that mean the acceleration of the ball equals the following: $\overrightarrow{a}=\text{acceleration of drag}+\text{acceleration due to gravity}=-\frac{1}{2m}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} -g\hat{j}$? I'm just confused on the physics part of this calculation.

Comment: split all vectors into $x$ and $y$ components and solve each separately.

Comment: I can do that. I just want to make sure the equation is correct thus far.

Comment: Yes it’s correct